# substract 5 minute from current Date and time javascript

Tags: javascript

I have problem while substracting time from current date. My Code looks like:

```
var d = new Date(),
year = d.getUTCFullYear(),
month = ('0'+(d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
day = ('0'+d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2),
hour = ('0'+d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2),
minute = ('0'+d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2),
second = ('0'+d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);

var startDate = year+'/'+month+'/'+day+'-'+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;
console.log(startDate);
```

Comment: problem is this is current time and i want substract 5 minutes from this time

Comment: minute = ('0'+d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2)-(5),

Comment: Hint: try the Date .getMinutes() and .setMinutes() methods to adjust the time *before* extracting all the pieces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the milliseconds of the date variable, substract 5 minutes and create a new date object from it:

```
var d = new Date()
// d = Mon Feb 29 2016 08:00:09 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
var milliseconds = Date.parse(d)
// 1456729209000
milliseconds = milliseconds - (5 * 60 * 1000)
// - 5 minutes
d = new Date(milliseconds)
// d = Mon Feb 29 2016 07:55:04 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use like below

```
var fiveMinuteAgo = new Date( Date.now() - 1000 * (60 * 5) )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are ready to use new date manipulation js  called as moment js.

You can simply do it in one function as below:

```
moment().subtract(5, 'minutes');
```

[Moment JS Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)

Comment: Adding 14kb of code for a task that only requires 3 commands seems a little excessive.

Comment: just a recommendation. Suitable for complex date driven applications.

Answer (score 1):

You could use like this

```js
var original = new Date();
var subtract5min = new Date();
alert("before : " + original);
subtract5min.setTime(original.getTime() - 5*60*1000);
alert("after : " + subtract5min);
```

Comment: This can result in negative minutes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply substract by

`minute = ('0'+d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2)-5`

```js
var d = new Date(),
    year = d.getUTCFullYear(),
    month = ('0'+(d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
    day = ('0'+d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2),
    hour = ('0'+d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2),
    minute = ('0'+d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2),
    second = ('0'+d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);

    if (minute>=5)
      minute = minute-5;
    else {
      minute = (parseInt(minute) + 60) - 5;
      hour = hour - 1;
    }

    var startDate = year+'/'+month+'/'+day+'-'+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;
    alert(startDate);
```

Comment: This could result in a negative number. (Also, it would need to be done *before* the slice.)

Comment: @Munawir, I doubt you need if condition if you follow approach of `getMinutes/setMinues` as suggested by _nnnnnn_